# AWS CodeDeploy connecting to GitHub: Error extracting tar archive: 2 -- is there a tarball size limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-api, aws-code-deploy

I have integrated CodeDeploy with one of my projects on GitHub for automatic deployment. Until recently, it has been working, but is now failing at the DownloadBundle stage with the following error: "Error extracting tar archive: 2"

The repository is quite large (~8.3GB) and was wondering if anyone knew if there was an upper limit on the size the tarball which the CodeDeploy-agent fetches.

Everything has been updated (including the CodeDeploy-agent) on my EC2 instance.

The relevant parts of the aws_log_wire appear below in the event this is helpful:

2016-03-23 03:18:10 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(23967)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Requesting URL: 'https://[MY_PROJECT]/tarball/[REMOVED_COMMIT_ID]'
2016-03-23 03:25:37 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(23967)]: InstanceAgent::LinuxUtil: Error extracting tar archive: 2
2016-03-23 03:25:37 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(23967)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2016-03-23 03:25:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(23967)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.092371 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"$

2016-03-23 03:25:38 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(23967)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: RuntimeError - Error extracting tar archive: 2 - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/platform/linux$
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/platform/linux_util.rb:30:in `extract_tar'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:292:in`unpack_bundle'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:99:in `block in <class:CommandExecutor>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:63:in`execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:132:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in`perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:38:in`block in run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:37:in`run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:70:in `block in run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in`with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:69:in `run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:33:in`block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in`start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:202:in `block in spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in`fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in `spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:192:in`block in spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in `times'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in`spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:134:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:37:in`block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in`start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:37:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in`call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:262:in`block in call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in`call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:84:in`'

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue with a < 2 kB archive, so I don't think this is due to the size of the archive. 
After some research, I found out that for some reason, CodeDeploy downloads my .tar.gz bundle as *bundle.**tar*** and treats it as a ZIP file.

I'm not sure why (I'm specifying *bundleType=tgz* in my deployment script), but using *bundleType=zip* solves the problem.

Comment: Hmm. All of my prior bundles that have worked for the same application are bundle.tar.. This issue arose only when we recently added a huge asset checkin, which is why I suspected the repo size...

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to what @christophetd posted. We recently upgraded some of our hosts to the latest codedeployment-agent (1.0.1.934) and started receiving the same error (RuntimeError - Error extracting tar archive: 2). Our solution was to add `bundleType=zip` to our deploy script as well.

```
--github-location commitId=12367127689127893123789,repository=org/repo,bundleType=zip
```